# what are other ways to do ping in vb.net or c# other than the way found here?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

what are other ways to do ping in vb.net or c# other than the way found [here](http://www.developersource.net/DevPage.aspx?ID=7):

```
Dim pinger As New System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
MessageBox.Show(pinger.Send("192.168.0.119").Status.ToString)
```

Comment: What's specifically wrong with this method?

Comment: why would you want to do it any other way? if `ping` is really what you want to do, then `NetworkInformation.Ping` is the proper way to do it. if you really just want to check if a website is up and running, there are other ways to do that, and you should rephrase your question to match what you want to know.

Comment: i'm sure there exists other optimal methods that are not managed by the .net framework. specifically i would like to know how to do ping using an api call to a dll written in c/c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a WMI class which encapsulates ping, [WIN32_PingStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394350%28VS.85%29.aspx), which you can use from a client with XP/2003 or later.

Comment: WMI can also be remoted, so you can do a ping from a second computer to a third.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch cmd.exe and execute the ping command by writing to [StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) To retrieve results read from StandardOutput.